# Permission denied in PHP

Tags: php, permissions, centos, chmod, mkdir

My script generates a directory for photos that user uploads but permissions for that generated directory shows as `r----x--t` even though i specify 777 in php

```
if (!is_dir($dir.$new_id)) {
    $new_dir = $dir.$new_id.'/';
    mkdir($new_dir, 777, true);
    $thumbnail_dir = $new_dir.'thumbnail/';
    if (!is_dir($thumbnail_dir)) {
        mkdir($thumbnail_dir, 777, true);   
    }
}
```

I should mention that i'm on hostinger free account that is running centos OS.

Comment: www-data user is not in owner or group of directory , you need to change it by chown command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set your umask temporarily to zero, the umask acts as a set of permissions that applications cannot set on files. Source : [http://php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.umask.php)

```
  $old = umask(0);
  if (!is_dir($dir.$new_id)) {
      $new_dir = $dir.$new_id.'/';
      mkdir($new_dir, 0777, true);
      $thumbnail_dir = $new_dir.'thumbnail/';
      if (!is_dir($thumbnail_dir)) {
          mkdir($thumbnail_dir, 0777, true);   
      }
  }
  umask($old);
  if ($old != umask()) {
     die('An error occurred while changing back the umask');
  }
```

Comment: same thing happens, directory is still on r----x--t

Comment: and with `mkdir($new_dir, 0777, true);  chmod($new_dir, 0777);`  ?

Comment: www-data user is  not in owner or group of directory , you need to change it by chown command